# Reason for comment deletion

Tags: support, deleted-comments

Can someone explain to me why I had a comment deleted on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27584554/2850651)? It was still listed in my mobile app, so I have it verbatim:

> @perissf I amended my answer to hopefully clarify a bit.

As far as I know, the OP is not notified when an answer to one of their posts is edited, so I left the comment to ensure that they'd notice the change. I would like to know the reason for the deletion. Should I just flag the post for moderator attention and ask there? Or can someone here tell me?

Comment: Folks sure are downvote happy on Meta. Seems like a reasonable question to me.

Comment: I can see how it could come across as petty whining, and I almost deleted the question after I'd realized that it was most likely the OP flagging it as obsolete. I left it, though, 'cause I don't have a lot of experience asking questions and I wanted to become familiar with the details. E.g., I used to think OPs were notified about any comment on an answer to their question, but apparently not.

Comment: LOL I asked a question like this couple weeks ago and it got down-voted to hell.

Comment: I reply `you're welcome` to OP, and get deleted too !

Comment: @JohnJoe It's nothing to be concerned about. Often, when the OP sees a comment like that, they'll flag it themselves as obsolete, meaning that they've seen it, but it doesn't really need to stick around anymore. The longer I've been here, the more I've come to appreciate a tidy comment section, so I'll flag comments for deletion after I've seen them, if they don't contain any discussion relevant to the question or answer. It just makes it easier to read through for the next users who might come across the post. I'm sure the OP appreciated your thanks, and was just cleaning up.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your comment was:

> @perissf I amended my answer to hopefully clarify a bit. –  Mike M. 13 hours ago

It was flagged by someone as obsolete.  I say someone because we can't see who flagged comments.  A moderator reviewed the flag and deleted the comment. The comment was around for about 5 hours before being deleted, so it is entirely possible that the OP saw it making it, in fact, obsolete.

Comment: Gotcha. I guess I was just concerned that someone flagged it as fluff, or rude, or something. I would bet it was the OP's flag, as the answer was accepted shortly after I'd noticed the comment was gone, and very shortly after I'd posted here. Sorry for causing a scene for nothing! Thanks a bunch.

Comment: No worries, by the way I'm going to clean the comments up under your question, so don't cause another scene. :)

Comment: So tempted to flag that as obsolete. @bluefeet

Comment: Maybe 5 hours is too little. People leaving on the opposite side of the plante may have different day/night periods (and maybe they don't connect regularly). I guess 12 hours would be a better threshold. My 2 cent.

Comment: Yeah, but the only plausible reason for somebody flagging it as obsolete (as opposed to too chatty, off-topic or whatever) is that it was, in fact, obsolete, probably because the recipient had read it and understood it.

Comment: @tripleee I'm sure that's what it was, but I hadn't even considered the obsolete flag option at the time. I've just never had an OP tidy up before. It kinda freaked me out.

Comment: I usually try to remove my comments if they're no longer relevant. It's important to remember, because the question and answers are useful to people in the future too, and they don't need to see you asking for more details or saying you updated some post.