# Why was my comment deleted?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-comments

A few days ago I added one comment on this answer
[Glide-4.0.0 Missing placeholder, error, GlideApp and does not resolve its method placeholder, error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50253398/7666442)

I asked some question to the user about his answer

My comment was something like below but not exactly the same

> `We have no need to use RequestOptions also.` No you have used **`centerCropTransform()`** that statically import `import static com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions.centerCropTransform;` that's no need to use `RequestOptions` if your remove `centerCropTransform()` than  you get  error like method does not resolve

I don't know the reason why my comment is deleted

I know we can flag the comment like

- rude or abusive
- no longer needed
- in need of moderator intervention

Please Note I have already visited similar questions

[Reason for comment deletion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280879/reason-for-comment-deletion)

[Why was my comment removed from this question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368079/why-was-my-comment-removed-from-this-question/368085#368085)

but it did not help to understand in my case

So my questions are:

1. Why was my comment deleted?
2. Did I make a mistake in my comment?
3. Which flag was used on my comment?
4. Can someone explain the reasoning behind it?

Comment: Probably related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295837/why-is-my-comment-deleted (very similar title)

Comment: @SurajRao yes but i didn't understand why my comment is deleted i  have just asked the question in comment and i'm sure that i didn't have asked rude tone

Comment: and also i'm sure that the comment is not deleted by that's why i have asked the question

Comment: The comment under the answer there looks fine. I might have flagged the comment as stated in this meta-question because it's confusing and has a lot of typos. What should "than you error like method does not resolve" mean?

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one, I read that comment and really did not get what it was trying to say. I still wouldn't have flagged, I would just assume that if you have domain knowledge you'll get it.

Comment: Also realise, you've posted a comment under another answer to a question you've answered, so there's a conflict of interest to a point. If the comment is flagged, it's reasonable to remove it.

Comment: @YvetteColomb   i have put comment for a reason in his answer because i think the other use need to update his answer and  *`it's reasonable to remove it.`* can u explain  why

Comment: @NileshRathod  That's your opinion under that answer. Allow the voters to decide how right or wrong that answer is. You've said your piece. Obviously at least one person doesn't want the comment there, But you've successfully brought it to meta and got it reinstated. If it's flagged again, it will be deleted. Are you going to bring another meta question?

Comment: @YvetteColomb *`Are you going to bring another meta question?`*  nop i juts want to know why my comment is deleted  *`Allow the voters to decide how right or wrong that answer is`* yes you are right but i just want to inform that user that there is mistake in his answer did i make some mistake to adding that comment

Comment: @NileshRathod No not at all. There is no mistake in adding the comment. The comment is helpful. But it was under another person's answer and you had posted an answer, so if the comment is objected you can understand, it's hard to keep it there. You've said what you think. If it bothers other people, let it go and let the community decide, it's not that important.

Comment: @YvetteColomb thank u for your help i understand

Comment: @NileshRathod you're welcome, you can understand, if someone leaves a comment under your post and you may not agree with it, or someone else may flag it, we have to consider all parties. Comments are not meant to be permanent.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I'm very confused about the relevance of which post a comment is attached to or whether the commenter has another answer on the same question. Why should that have any bearing on whether a comment is deleted or not? All content on this site should be judged by the *content*, not the person who created it.

Comment: @YvetteColomb: A conflict of interest (which, frankly, I don't even see) is not a valid reason to purge a comment. You made up that rule. What worries me is that you are a moderator, and have the tools to establish your made-up rules.

Comment: So, conflict of interest?  Probably should delete any question/answer by Jeff Atwood.  I mean, he's a cofounder, right?  By that logic, he should have no content on this site. :|

Comment: Not trying to be mean, but there are several glaring grammatical mistakes and typos in your comment ("FIY"??). If you spent a little more time on polishing it and adding in some punctuation, it could look more like something worth keeping around at a glance... and comment flags are generally handled at a glance. Right now it takes effort to parse it sufficiently to determine whether it's of any value. Also while you claim "I asked some question to the user about his answer" there is no question in your comment.

Comment: @YvetteColomb: _"Also realise, you've posted a comment under another answer to a question you've answered, so there's a conflict of interest to a point. If the comment is flagged, it's reasonable to remove it"_ I don't even know where to begin with how deeply flawed this logic is. Please tell me this is not how flags are handled on Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Your comment was fine and I've undeleted it. We generally don't scrutinise some comment flags too hard - the "no longer needed" flag which was used "looked" reasonable given the content of the answer and a mod chose to delete it. I wouldn't worry too much about it - you didn't do anything untoward.

Comment: I always thought that comment deletion was "hard deletion" (i.e. the data was just gone from the database for good).

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta I would be surprised if anything is hard deleted unless required by law. SE can use all the information in the database, for the their own stats for example.

Comment: I believe they delete nothing. That's the only time when they delete: "And of course, should you wish, you may also request the permanent deletion of your account, in which case all personal information collected on you will be removed from our servers and encrypted (except, in some cases your IP address required for security purposes, site maintenance, and spam protection)." but some information still remains.

Comment: @TuğberkKaanDuman: *"removed from our servers **and encrypted**"* - Doesn't sound like anything is being deleted here either.

Comment: Recently, I posted a question as a comment: "why was this question downvoted?" which was removed. I then added a second comment citing that the previous comment was removed which ended being removed as well. How did I take this action? Seems like some with higher reputation HATE their actions being scrutinized and being brought into question. Instead of simply providing a straight answer to the question, they used their power to silence those with an opinion that differs to theirs. You might question my opinion, but there is a growing population in Reddit that feels this way as well.

Comment: @hfontanez "Why was this downvoted" is among the easiest comments to get deleted. They are entirely useless.

Comment: I think is beneficial to future users to see an explanation as to why this question (or answer) has this many downvotes with no explanation whatsoever. I have seen too many well asked questions being downvoted for no good reason. And the fact that when this is questioned, you are censored by your "comment" being removed helps no one and instead fuels the feeling that what I previously stated might be true.

Comment: @hfontanez That's great and all, but by the time you post such a comment, the person who downvoted is long gone. You'd be better off asking for something actionable (such as, "How can I improve this question?")

Comment: @KevinB I can't even begin to count the times an answer of mine has been downvoted (with explanation) that the answer only helps the OP and not other people in the future and for an answer to be of good quality, MUST help others as well. Yet, as you stated now, it is only about the OP. I am sorry, you cannot have it both ways.

Comment: @hfontanez how is what i stated only about the op? "I" can be anyone. Asking for the reason some random person who's gone did something is futile.

Comment: @KevinB Sorry, I misread something you posted.

Comment: @KevinB I don't expect everyone to be me, but I never downvote a question or answer without 1) leaving an explanation as to why I have done it. Even in some cases, I warn the OP about the question or answer being incorrect, invalid, or low quality AND I wait for a reasonable amount of time to allow the OP to either fix or delete it. That is helpful to the OP and any other person that comes in the future looking for answers. Deleting a comment of someone questioning a downvote helps who exactly? (or downvoting without a reason?)

Comment: @hfontanez I used to also leave comments with each and every downvote explaining why i downvoted, however, more often than not, it resulted in useless discussion and even negative actions on my account (see my question list.) It's far more useful to instead ignore the downvote and provide critisizm/feedback that doesn't require a downvote to be relevant.

Comment: @KevinB "_and even negative actions on my account_" Isn't that interesting? You are doing the right thing which is extremely helpful to countless people and yet, the end result. Again, one of the reasons why there is a growing population of past and current users who HATE SO for similar reasons.

Comment: @hfontanez the end result in my case is, i still downvote, and i still leave comments, but my comments are more useful now. "Why was this downvoted?" is never useful. At best, it is confrontational/rude.

Comment: @KevinB I was referring to your last posted question. But anyway, I think it is wrong to delete a comment that challenges a downvote; even if the person who did it never answers it.

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR**
 *Comments are intended to be transient, if the comment has reached it's intended audience, it's no longer needed.*

#### No longer needed

I handled the flag to the comment.

It was "no longer needed". All things weighed, how long the comment was there, I thought it was reasonable to delete the comment.

As in this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280893/3956566):

> It was flagged by someone as obsolete. I say someone because we can't
>   see who flagged comments. A moderator reviewed the flag and deleted
>   the comment. The comment was around for about 5 hours before being
>   deleted, so it is entirely possible that the OP saw it making it, in
>   fact, obsolete.

In this case the comment was around for over 8 hours.

The comment is offering a criticism of the answer.

The comment author [states](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368423/why-was-my-comment-deleted?noredirect=1#comment593372_368423):

> i just want to inform that user that there is mistake in his answer

As for the comment and it's usefulness. The comment is showing a basic misunderstanding of the answer. The answer (paraphrasing) is stating that requestOptions does not need to be explicitly imported, as it's imported within the larger package of the Glide App class.

The comment doesn't really make sense. It's avoiding the remainder of the answer.

So let's assume the author of the answer read the comment and didn't agree with the comment, how long do we keep the comment around? Who was the intended audience of the comment? By the commenters own words, the author of the answer. The comment has become noise under the post.

#### Do leave critical feedback, but put important stuff into posts

To be clear I'm *not* saying don't leave critical feedback under posts. I am saying, unless the comment has pertinent information to the post that is required for future readers (the intended audience), it's unreasonable to expect it to be permanent.

The other issue, comments are supposed to be transient, if there is something of value that needs to be kept on the site, post it into an answer, either as an edit to an existing answer, or a new answer explaining the addition information.

In terms of mods handling comments, to give you an idea, the mods have deleted in excess of 20,000 comments this month alone. So as [Jon said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368426/3956566):

> We generally don't scrutinise some comment flags too hard ...

#### Community concerns

There seems to be some upset over my comments (which is fair) about conflict of interest and upon examination of how I handle flags, the author of the comment is irrelevant. The comment is either useful or is not or no longer useful, regardless of the author.

Comment: Comments are to provide legitimate criticism or requests for improvement to posts. As such, I would like more of a bias towards comment flagging and deletion, especially if the user and/or moderator is a Subject Matter Expert (an SME) on the subject at hand. A page cluttered with nonsense comments seems far less desirable than a clean one with a question and multiple great answers.

Comment: The last paragraph doesn't really answer [my comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368423/why-was-my-comment-deleted#comment593987_368423) or the [one by LRiO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368423/why-was-my-comment-deleted#comment594236_368423). You mentioned this "conflict of interest" but now you're saying it didn't matter in the first place, so which is it? If it doesn't matter, why bring it up?

Comment: First off, I'm asking for clarification only, which I think is pretty reasonable given your original comment coupled with the fact that you are now a mod here, so I don't particularly appreciate your irascible response. Secondly and to the point, your answer didn't explicitly say that you had *changed your mind*. Anyway, there seems to be no point in carrying on with this discussion, so I'm off to do more important things.