# My comment is deleted with no obvious reason

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-comments, specific-comment

Note: the "duplicate" link/question is exactly what I have put into my OP. And one can see that only the questions-part are the same with it. I.e., the situation is mine. Just like I said, *"I have the same questions with him, but my situation is different."*

A few days ago I asked a question and then followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73591090/2125837) up with comments ***for clarifications***. My comment/follow-question was long, so I have to split it into two, with the first one ended with *"Just like my follow up Q"*, and my second comment begins with *"Just like my follow up question posted in ..."*

My second comment is the very important part of follow-up question, as the first part was just to building the background info up. So I was astonished to find that the most important part of the follow-up question was deleted.

From [Why was my comment deleted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368423/why-was-my-comment-deleted), by [AskNilesh](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7666442/asknilesh):

> I don't know the reason why my comment is deleted.
>
> I know we can flag the comment like
>
> - rude or abusive
> - no longer needed
> - in need of moderator intervention

I have already visited similar questions like,

[Why was my comment deleted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368423/why-was-my-comment-deleted)

[Reason for comment deletion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280879/reason-for-comment-deletion)

[Why was my comment removed from this question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368079/why-was-my-comment-removed-from-this-question/368085#368085)

> but they did not help to understand in my case
>
> So my questions are:
>
> 1. Why was my comment deleted?
> 2. Did I make a mistake in my comment?
> 3. Which flag was used on my comment?
> 4. Can someone explain the reasoning behind it?

From [Why was my comment deleted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368423/why-was-my-comment-deleted), the accepted answer was:

> Your comment was fine and I've undeleted it.

I'd hope to get the same result if no one can give a clear explanation.

Comment: Questions 1 and 4 (maybe even 2) are the same in this post.

Comment: Questions 1 to 4 are all the same in this post @TheFungusAmongUs. I.e., I have the same questions, but the situation is different.

Comment: I believe @TheFungusAmongUs is talking about *"Why was my comment deleted?"* and *"Can someone explain the reasoning behind it?"* xpt. I fail to see how these are different questions; they're just different ways of asking the same question. The reason and the why are the same.

Comment: @Larnu Yes, I was just mentioning that these could be merged into one question. Unfortunately, I do not have enough rep to edit posts on meta.

Comment: As for the matter at hand, without seeing the comment it is difficult to know. However, comments are generally not for asking follow-up questions: see [What is the best way to ask follow-up questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions) NLN flags on these sorts of comments can result in them being deleted, and perhaps it was only cast on one of your comments.

Comment: @Larnu,Questions 1 to 4 are all copied from https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368423/,  I.e., I have the same questions with, but the situation is different. But feel free to change/edit it to whatever you like.

Comment: If they are all the same question, and that question has been answered, @xpt , then I fail to see why you need to ask the question too. If your question is different, then why not ask your *own* question(s)?

Comment: As I explained @Larnu, _the situation is different_.

Comment: Then, again, ask your own question. Don't copy someone else's question and then just say "the situation is different".

Comment: I did edited my question @RobertLongson later, but my second part of the important question is gone.

Comment: @Larnu, the link you gave me is exactly what I have put into my OP. and you can see that it is only the last 4 question-part that I copied. I.e., the situation is what I put in mine. Just like I said, _"I have the same questions with him, but my situation is different. "_

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs, The "What is the the best way to ask follow up questions" link you gave me is about _"**further** questions about the problem or I come up with new questions that are closely **related**. "_ whereas mine was asking for clarification for the unclear answer.

Comment: @xpt Ah ok, it's not a follow-up question then - it's a request for clarification. I think framing it as a "follow-up" question may have prompted a NLN flag which then resulted in your comment being deleted. Again, without the actual content of the comment, it's hard to tell.

Comment: This very unclear, please reorganize & make all references to things clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.  That includes saying why a reference link is there & what its content has to do with your post; don't expect us to read links, make your post self-contained. PS What '"duplicate" link/question'?

Comment: Your comment ended with "*I'm sad to see my carefully written question get downvoted without even an explanation."* [Such comments are regularly deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/393914). This appears very much like a whine. Even if you dislike that characterization, there is no need to discuss voting in the comments. Ever. The rest of your comment was effectively letting the answerer know that you'd asked another question. That's annoying, so don't do that. If someone wants to find questions to answer, there are already ways of doing that. They don't need you nagging them.

Answer (score 9):

> Why was my comment deleted?
> Can someone explain the reasoning behind it?

Because you should not have commented like that.

> Did I make a mistake in my comment?

Yes.

> then follow this answer up with comments for clarifications. My comment/follow-question was long, so I have to split it into two, with the first one ended with "Just like my follow up Q", and my second comment begins with "Just like my follow up question posted in ..."

*Do not use the comments to ask a follow-up question.* Especially not if it is going to take more than one comment just to contain the question.

Please keep in mind that Stack Overflow is **not a discussion forum**, and try to get right to the point.

The question has the same problem. My eyes glaze over staring at it and trying to make any sense out of it.

Posts on Stack Overflow are supposed to contain **one**, *focused*, *specific*, *clear* question.

Even the question here on Meta is much longer than it needs to be.

> I have already visited similar questions... but they did not help to understand in my case

Well, yes; there are many reasons that comments get deleted, so there's no reason to expect other questions about other comments to be relevant.

---

Since an object example seems to be necessary. Here is the existing first comment:

> Thanks Dmitri! As you can see, all my questions are around, "ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code", and from your previous answer, "it's not recommended to inline JMeter Functions or Variables into JSR223 scripts", because I'm not too familiar with JMeter, not Groovy, so I'm having difficulties understanding what they exactly mean. The "best practice" made it more clearer by saying "does not use any variable using ${varName}", however, as you can see from my Questions 1 and 3, it is not 100% true. Just like my follow up Q

(I cannot see the second comment; AFAICT, the privilege of seeing deleted posts only extends to posts.)

Here's how to write the comment more succinctly:

> Where you say "ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code" and "it's not recommended to inline JMeter Functions or Variables into JSR223 scripts", what exactly does this mean? If it is "best practice" to "not use any variable using ${varName}", why do I see examples that do?

Although it is probably not necessary to write that much anyway. There's no point in asking why people do things that violate "best practices"; the answer (which you will see across the entire industry, across time and space, across every profession) is that some people are incompetent, have deadlines, personally disagree with the "best practices" document, or some combination of those things. For any more detail than that, you would have to ask *the person who did it*.

Comment: Again, I was asking for clarification for the unclear answer, and I think it is rude just to say it is unclear. That's why I spent so many words to explain in detail why it is unclear. Have you seen my 2nd part of the comment @Karl? Would you give your comment based on my 2nd part of the comment please?

Comment: It should not take two entire comments to say why something is unclear.

Comment: That's personal choice/style. I'd like to give as much info as necessary. IHMO, such practice should not be considered a sin. Please comment based on my 2nd part of the comment BTW.

Comment: "I'd like to give as much info as necessary" Your writing style **does not give more info**, and **makes things more difficult and less enjoyable to read**.

Comment: I'd prefer the mod who did the operation to give the answer, not based on guess or by someone with such strong personal opinion (based on your _"how to write the comment more succinctly"_ suggestion, and the comments that follows, I have a sense that you didn't even tried to understand what I was trying to say. For e.g., the "best practice" is not from some people who _"are incompetent, have deadlines, personally disagree with the "best practices" document, or some combination of those things. "_. It is the **official JMeter best practice**)

Comment: @xpt: "I'd prefer..." I think that a basic rule of Stack Overflow, and of any free help or Q&A site staffed by volunteers is that a poster may have a preference on responses to their questions, but unless those responses are rude/abusive, there's not much that they can *or should* do about them.

Comment: While everything you say is true, the real problem (at least, it would have been the deciding reason why I would have deleted the comment, had I been the mod who handled the flag on it) is that the deleted comment contained a whine about downvoting of the question. That was really the cherry on top of a useless comment, serving little purpose other than to nag the author of the answer. *Especially* since the comment you quoted is still there, without the complaint about downvoting, and seems very much redundant with the deleted comment (which was posted after it).